# can't change a value in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code should get an array with zero or 1 values, if any element is 0, it should switch it to 1 and also switch the status of its divisors. The problem is that the second if seems not to work and it does not change the 1 status to 0. I don't get why, can anyone help me?

```
data = input()
L = list(data.split())
L2 = np.array(L,int)
L3 = np.zeros(len(L2),int)
for i in range(len(L2)-1, -1, -1):
    if ( L2[i] == 0) :
        L2[i] = 1
        L3[i] = 1

        for j in range(0, i) : 
            if ((i+1)%(j+1) == 0 & L2[j] == 0) :
                L2[j] = 1

            if ((i+1)%(j+1) == 0 & L2[j] == 1) :
                L2[j] =0  #this does not work



print(*L3)
```

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator in python you should use `and` keyword in your case.

Comment: Can you share some example input and output? Please see: [mcve]. Also, using so many loops when working with NumPy is a sign that something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
  if ((i+1)%(j+1) == 0 & L2[j] == 1) :
```

to

```
 if ((i+1)%(j+1) == 0 and L2[j] == 1) :
```

the first one is a math operation. Also for debugging these type of issues i usually add a print item in the if statement to make sure it's working. I hope this helps!